# unable to install flask-mysqldb module

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, cmd, flask-mysql

`pip install flask-mysqldb`

> C:\Users\prince>pip install flask-mysqldb Collecting flask-mysqldb
>   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/e3/955c845efe1aacf30c8e2607470544ede36aa1044f6382c809f13e014104/Flask-MySQLdb-0.2.0.tar.gz
>   Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in
>   c:\users\prince\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from flask-mysqldb) (1.1.1) Collecting mysqlclient (from
>   flask-mysqldb)   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/38/c5f8bac9c50f3042c8f05615f84206f77f03db79781db841898fde1bb284/mysqlclient-1.4.4.tar.gz
>   Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in
>   c:\users\prince\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (0.16.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in
>   c:\users\prince\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (2.10.1) Requirement already
>   satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in
>   c:\users\prince\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (1.1.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: click>=5.1 in
>   c:\users\prince\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (7.0) Requirement already satisfied:
>   MarkupSafe>=0.23 in
>   c:\users\prince\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (1.1.1) Installing
>   collected packages: mysqlclient, flask-mysqldb   Running setup.py
>   install for mysqlclient ... error
>       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>        command: 'c:\users\prince\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe'
>   -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\prince\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sb1cs5ex\mysqlclient\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\prince\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sb1cs5ex\mysqlclient\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\prince\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8l4u4qqk\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile
>            cwd: C:\Users\prince\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sb1cs5ex\mysqlclient\
>       Complete output (30 lines):
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win32-3.7
>       creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
>       creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
>       running build_ext
>       building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
>       creating build\temp.win32-3.7
>       creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
>       creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
>       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
>   /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0)
>   -D__version__=1.4.4 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" -Ic:\users\prince\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\prince\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt"
>   /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj
>   /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
>       _mysql.c
>       MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
>       error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe'
>   failed with exit status 2
>       ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>   'c:\users\prince\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe'
>   -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\prince\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sb1cs5ex\mysqlclient\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\prince\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sb1cs5ex\mysqlclient\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\prince\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8l4u4qqk\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 3):

It didn't worked for me too, but after clicking the link provided by @Suraj Virkar, I noticed that the command for installing is a little different. So instead of using

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

Just use

```
pip install Flask-MySQL
```

and i'm not really sure why but it worked! it must have someting to do with the versions i guess... oh and take note that you'll have to use

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

to import it on your project instead of using

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Those seems like different packages ... it might be a solution to the problem to change to another package but it seems to me that's not answering the question we have here.

Answer (score 0):

try to install flask-mysqldb by the following method

**Installation**

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

if you get error or system cannot fetch wheel file of flask-mysqldb, then go to [this link](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-MySQL/)

where you can download wheel file and then run that wheel file.

If this also not working then first install mysqlclient

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

and then install flask-mysqldb.